# summing the overlap in two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, cross-product

I am trying to calculate proximity measures between couples of scientific papers. When 2 of paper A's authors live in Amsterdam and 1 in New York, while 3 of paper B's authors live in Amsterdam, I want the result to be 3+2=5. I have two large matrices, where columns represent papers and rows represent cities. For example:

MatrixA:

```
                       A1      A2
```

DAVIS, CA USA                               4              . 
LOS ANGELES, CA USA            .              1 
PALO ALTO, CA USA                   .              1 
SACRAMENTO, CA USA            2              . 
SANTA MONICA, CA USA          .              2

and MatrixB:

```
                         B1
```

DAVIS, CA USA                                1 
LOS ANGELES, CA USA            2 
PALO ALTO, CA USA                     .
SACRAMENTO, CA USA             1 
SANTA MONICA, CA USA         2

the crossproduct of the two (MatrixA %*% t(MatrixB)) comes close to what I want. That'd give me, for A2-B1,

(0*1)+(1*2)+(1*0)+(0*1)+(2*2)=6

but what I want is:

(0*1)+(1+2)+(1*0)+(0*1)+(2+2)=7

So multiply when one's a 0, else add. Is there an efficient(!) way to achieve this, using R?

Comment: Please format your datasets

Comment: matrixA is 5*2 and t(matrixB) is 1*5 it means (MatrixA %*% t(MatrixB)) will throw an error.

Comment: @cryptomanic True. crossprod(x=MatrixA, y=MatrixB) will do.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is first to replace the `0`'s in your `A` and `B` matrices with `NA`, then **add** them and do a `colSums` with `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
A[A==0] <- NA
B[B==0] <- NA

## I'm assuming that you want to compare B to all columns of A
C <- colSums(A + rep(B,ncol(A)), na.rm=TRUE)
## A1 A2
##  8  7
```

**Data:**

```
A <- structure(c(4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A1", "A2")))
##     A1 A2
##[1,]  4  0
##[2,]  0  1
##[3,]  0  1
##[4,]  2  0
##[5,]  0  2

B <- structure(c(1, 2, 0, 1, 2), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "B1"))
##     B1
##[1,]  1
##[2,]  2
##[3,]  0
##[4,]  1
##[5,]  2
```